# Invalid date is appearing for everything when I use Configuration Generator code

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Using the Configuration Generator from http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples, I selected "ranges (with example predefined ranges)" and got the following JS:

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "ranges": {
        "Today": [
            "2016-10-17T04:27:01.501Z",
            "2016-10-17T04:27:01.501Z"
        ],
        "Yesterday": [
            "2016-10-16T04:27:01.501Z",
            "2016-10-16T04:27:01.501Z"
        ],
        "Last 7 Days": [
            "2016-10-11T04:27:01.501Z",
            "2016-10-17T04:27:01.501Z"
        ],
        "Last 30 Days": [
            "2016-09-18T04:27:01.501Z",
            "2016-10-17T04:27:01.501Z"
        ],
        "This Month": [
            "2016-10-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "2016-11-01T04:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "Last Month": [
            "2016-09-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "2016-10-01T04:59:59.999Z"
        ]
    },
    "startDate": "10/10/2016",
    "endDate": "10/16/2016"
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

Unfortunately, when I use that, every date is invalid. Here's a JS fiddle demonstrating what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/LgetLa6c/

If you hover over anything it'll say "Invalid date". The only thing that doesn't say "Invalid date" is "Custom Range".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of having dates formatted like `"2016-10-17T04:27:01.501Z"` the dates need to be formatted like `"10/17/2016"`.

The fact that the examples in the documentation don't work is pretty dumb meh.